# Building a quick GRU model for stock prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I am beginner in `RNNs` and would like to build a running model gated recurrent unit `GRU` for stock prediction.

I have a numpy array for the training data with this shape:

```
train_x.shape
(1122,20,320)
```

> ```
> `1122` represents the total amount timestamps I have
> `20` is the amount of timestamps I want to predict the future from
> `320` is the number of features (different stocks)
> ```

My `train_y.shape` is (1122,) and represents a binary variable with `1` and `0`. `1` is a buy `0` is a sell.

With that in my mind I started to attempt my `GRU` model as:

```
 def GRU_model(train_x,train_y,test_x,test_y):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Embedding(train_x.shape[0],50,input_length=320))
    model.add(layers.GRU(50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(train_x.shape[1],1),activation='tanh'))
    model.add(layers.GRU(50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(train_x.shape[1],1),activation='tanh'))
    model.add(layers.GRU(50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(train_x.shape[1],1),activation='tanh'))
    model.add(layers.GRU(50,activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dense(units=2))
    model.compile(optimizer=SGD(lr=0.01,decay=1e-7,momentum=0.9,nesterov=False),loss='mean_squared_error')
    
    model.fit(train_x,train_y,epochs=EPOCHS,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

    GRU_predict = model.predict(validation_x)

    return model,GRU_predict



my_gru_model,my_gru_predict = GRU_model(train_x,train_y,validation_x,validation_y)
ValueError: Input 0 of layer gru_42 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 20, 320, 50)
```

Clearly my input dimensions into the model are incorrect, but I do not understand how they should fit in, so the model can run smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have 1122 data samples and each sample has 20 time steps and each time step has 320 features and you want to teach your model to make a binary decision between buying and selling, try something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(1)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(20, 320), activation='tanh'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(50,activation='tanh'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01,decay=1e-7,momentum=0.9,nesterov=False),loss='binary_crossentropy')
print(model.summary())

train_x = tf.random.normal((1122, 20, 320))
train_y = tf.random.uniform((1122,), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=5, batch_size=16)
```

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 gru (GRU)                   (None, 20, 50)            55800     
                                                                 
 gru_1 (GRU)                 (None, 50)                15300     
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 51        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 71,151
Trainable params: 71,151
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Epoch 1/5
71/71 [==============================] - 5s 21ms/step - loss: 0.7050
Epoch 2/5
71/71 [==============================] - 2s 22ms/step - loss: 0.6473
Epoch 3/5
71/71 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 0.5513
Epoch 4/5
71/71 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 0.3640
Epoch 5/5
71/71 [==============================] - 1s 20ms/step - loss: 0.1258
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f4eac87e610>
```

Note that you have a single output node because your model is supposed to make a binary decision. This is also the reason why you have to use the loss function `binary_crossentropy`.

Regarding the GRU layer, it expects an input with the shape `(batch_size, timesteps, features)`, but the batch_size is inferred during training and is therefore omitted in the `input_shape`. Since the next GRU also requires this shape, you use the parameter `return_sequences=True` in the first GRU, which returns a sequence with the shape `(batch_size, 20, 50)` => one hidden state output `50` for each input time step `n`. Also you do not need an `Embedding` layer in your case. It is usually used to map integer sequences representing text into `n`-dimensional vector representations.

Comment: yes that works, could you please explain this line `model.add(tf.keras.layers.GRU(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(20, 320), activation='tanh'))` thanks

Comment: I tried using `Embedding` but it is not working, most probaly I'm getting wrong. :)

Comment: Updated answer with an explanation at the bottom.